# Inheritance in EF - How to include parent variables in the entity

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically I've created an entity that has a parent with variables which I obviously would like to include in the table storing the entity.

Here's the definition of the parent:

```
public class ProtectedProperty
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string SubId { get; set; }

        public int Downloads { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public UserProfile Owner { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ProtectedPropertyType Type { get; set; }
    }
```

And here's the property that inherits from the parent (this one has a table in the DB):

```
[Table("ProtectedPassword")]
    public class ProtectedPassword : ProtectedProperty
    {

        [Required]
        //[StringLength(maximumLength:56)]
        [MinLength(3)]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public ProtectedPassword(string name, UserProfile owner, string password)
        {
            Name = name;
            Owner = owner;
            Password = password;
            SubId = PublicUtility.GenerateRandomString(8, 0);
            Type = ProtectedPropertyType.Password;
        }
```

The issue is however that when I look in the table definition in the DB I only see 2 properties for ProtectedPassword:
Password and PropertyId

I'd like to have the other variables included as well (such as Owner, Name etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Remove the `[Table]` attribute.

It causes that the inheritance in your model is mapped via [Table-Per-Type (TPT)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx). With TPT properties of the base and the derived class are split into two separate tables.

If you want to have all properties in a single table you have two options:

- With [Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) all properties of the base class and **all** derived classes will be stored in a single table. TPH is the default inheritance mapping that will be applied if you don't add a `[Table]` attribute or an explicit mapping with Fluent API.
- With [Table-Per-Concrete-Type (TPC)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx) every concrete type in the inheritance hierarchy gets its own table that will hold its properties and the properties of its base classes in the inheritance chain. Actually in your situation this mapping won't help because your base class is concrete as well and not `abstract`.